# Eliminar un registro en una base de datos sqlite desde una Listview con el metodo OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas comunidad soy estudiante de programación y estoy incursionando en android;

Estoy realizando una aplicación la cual tiene un listview que se alimenta de una base de datos sqlite, atreves de un Array, mi intención es que cuando mantengo presionado unos segundos en el registro que quiero eliminar me pregunte con un método Alerdialog si lo quiero eliminar.
El problema es que me lo elimina del listview pero no de la base,como debo escribir o llamar al método eliminar.

Este código es parte del Activity ListarBASE

```
    lista=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lista);
    LisInfo=llenar_lv();
    Adaptador= new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_item_listapersonal,LisInfo);
    lista.setAdapter(Adaptador);

    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() 
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
    final int posicion=i ;
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListarBase.this);
            dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");
            dialogo1.setMessage("¿ Elimina este Registro ?");
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    LisInfo.remove(posicion);
                    Adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
            dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                }
            });
            dialogo1.show();
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

EL LISTVIEW SE CARGA CON ESTE METODO

```
    public ArrayList llenar_lv(){
    ArrayList<String> lista =new ArrayList<>();
    BaseHelper admin = new BaseHelper(this,"ADMIN", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BsD = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "select * FROM token";
    Cursor Resgistros =BsD.rawQuery(q,null);
    if (Resgistros.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            lista.add(Resgistros.getString(0)+" <> "+
                    Resgistros.getString(1)+" <> "+
                    Resgistros.getString(2));
        }while (Resgistros.moveToNext());
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Y LA BASE DE DATOS ES ASI:

```
 public class BaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public BaseHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseHelper) {
        BaseHelper.execSQL("create table TOKEN (dni int primary key, nombre text, token text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma de como poder eliminar el registro, por medio del nombre almacenado en la base de datos:

```
public void eliminaRegistroPorNombre(String nombre) {
    BaseHelper admin = new BaseHelper(this,"ADMIN", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BsD = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    BsD.delete("token","nombre=?", new String[]{nombre});
}
```

Pero hay algo importante que comentar de acuerdo a la consulta en tu `ListView` estas imprimiendo un texto que contiene el `id`, `nombre` y `token`, algo similar a :

```
"12 <> Cristian <> c123ABCD"
```

por lo tanto obten el texto de la lista:

```
String textoLista =  (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

obten el nombre de la lista

```
String nombre = textoLista.substring(textoLista.indexOf("<>") + 2, textoLista.lastIndexOf("<>")).trim();
```

y este nombre usalo para eliminar el registro en la base de datos:

```
eliminaRegistroPorNombre(nombre);
```

tu código entonces sería:

```
 lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() 
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
    final int posicion=i ;
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListarBase.this);
            dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");
            dialogo1.setMessage("¿ Elimina este Registro ?");
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    LisInfo.remove(posicion);
                    Adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //*Elimina registro.
                    String textoLista =  (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    String nombre = textoLista.substring(textoLista.indexOf("<>") + 2, textoLista.lastIndexOf("<>")).trim();
                    eliminaRegistroPorNombre(nombre);


                }
            });
            dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                }
            });
            dialogo1.show();
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Gracias por la respusta, consulta no seria mejor eliminar por dni?

Comment: @cristiangareis si claro, lo que te di es una opción pero, en el caso que comentas debes modificar el query para eliminar en base a el dni y obtener el dni del texto que agregas en el elemento del ListView

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por la info.

Comment: Buenas tardes, despues de muchas pruebas pude realizar la eliminacion como me lo sujeristes jorge , lo que no consigo todabia es como obtener el String dni en  ves del nombre para poder hacer la eliminacion en base a el dni.